# Travis test fails but passes on local machine

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

The following test loads all Markdown files from a path. It works locally, but randomly fails on Travis. Sometimes, it passes without any failures, sometimes it passes on some PHP versions. The class which is being tested is [here](https://github.com/hassankhan/Zepto/blob/develop/library/Zepto/FileLoader/MarkdownLoader.php)

```
public function testLoadMultipleFiles()
{
    $index_content = "<h2>This is a Sub Page Index</h2>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
        . "<p>This is index.md in the 'sub' folder.</p>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
        . "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
        . "<p>Donec ultricies tristique nulla et mattis.</p>" . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL
        . "<p>Phasellus id massa eget nisl congue blandit sit amet id ligula.</p>" . PHP_EOL;

    $sub_page_content = "<h2>This is a Sub Page</h2>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
            . "<p>This is page.md in the 'sub' folder.</p>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
            . "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
            . "<p>Donec ultricies tristique nulla et mattis.</p>" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
            . "<p>Phasellus id massa eget nisl congue blandit sit amet id ligula.</p>". PHP_EOL;

    // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
    $parser = $this->getMock('Michelf\MarkdownInterface', array('defaultTransform', 'transform'));

    $parser::staticExpects($this->at(0))
            ->method('defaultTransform')
            ->will($this->returnValue($index_content));

    $parser::staticExpects($this->at(1))
            ->method('defaultTransform')
            ->will($this->returnValue($sub_page_content));

    $loader = new MarkdownLoader($parser);

    $files['sub/index.md'] = array(
        'meta'    => array(
            'title'         => 'Sub Page Index'
        ),
        'content' => $index_content
    );

    $files['sub/page.md'] = array(
        'meta'    => array(
            'title'         => 'Sub Page'
        ),
        'content' => $sub_page_content
    );

    $result = $loader->load(ROOT_DIR . 'content/sub', array('md'));
    $this->assertEquals($files, $result);
}
```

Travis shows the following on a failed run:

```
There was 1 failure:
1) Zepto\FileLoader\MarkdownLoaderTest::testLoadMultipleFiles
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
     'sub/index.md' => Array (
         'meta' => Array (...)
-        'content' => '<h2>This is a Sub Page Index</h2>
+        'content' => '<h2>This is a Sub Page</h2>

-        <p>This is index.md in the 'sub' folder.</p>
+        <p>This is page.md in the 'sub' folder.</p>
@@ @@
         'meta' => Array (...)
-        'content' => '<h2>This is a Sub Page</h2>
+        'content' => '<h2>This is a Sub Page Index</h2>

-        <p>This is page.md in the 'sub' folder.</p>
+        <p>This is index.md in the 'sub' folder.</p>

         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

         <p>Donec ultricies tristique nulla et mattis.</p>

         <p>Phasellus id massa eget nisl congue blandit sit amet id ligula.</p>
         '
     )
 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the long delay for awnsering.

Just a guess, but do you use Mac OS X locally?

Mac OS X returns lists in alphabetical order, but on linux the file system lists files in a random order.

In your tests error message, you can see that each file read was getting the opposite of what it expects, `index` or `sub page`, leading me to believe that the tests failing due to directory listing coming in a random error( The other times when it passes the file system returns the two files in the correct order). I don't know any phpunit so I can't help you with the specifics unfortunately.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that makes a lot of sense. I've since refactored/removed that code, so it doesn't matter now, but thank you for letting me know why.